# is a running container created by each RUN command during multistage build?

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker, sorry if my question sounds dumb.
below is a dockerfile from a textbook:

```
FROM diamol/base AS build-stage                  
RUN echo 'Building...' > /build.txt              #line 2

FROM diamol/base AS test-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /build.txt /build.txt
RUN echo 'Testing...' >> /build.txt              #line 6

FROM diamol/base
COPY --from=test-stage /build.txt /build.txt
CMD cat /build.txt
```

and the author says:

***The RUN instruction executes a command inside a container during the build, and any output from that command is saved in the image layer.***

My question is:

Since the author mentioned RUN instruction executes a command inside a **container** during the build, does it mean that in the first RUN command in line 2, a contianer is created based on the `diamol/base` image, and this container modify the content of the files then commit the change back to `diamol/base` image, then is container is terminated? and same thing happen in line 6,container created to run and then terminate, image gets updated, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Multiply posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/63574075/340790 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your understanding is correct. The `RUN <commands>` command in the Dockerfile is somewhat equivalent to

```
container = $(docker run base-image) #1
docker exec base-image commands #2 
docker commit $container #3
```

Since images are static, we'll need a running instance/process to execute our command. this is why a container is created from the base image. #1

After the execution of the command in #2, the changes are committed back #3, which means a new layer is created on top of the previous layers. This layer will contain the changes introduced by the container in (#2).

Comment: To be clear - `diamol:base` image is not modified. New, intermediate image is created by the command.